# Find the basis and dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ be given by 
$$A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & -2 & 1 \end{array} \right).$$
Consider the set $V$ of all $3 \times 3$ matrices that commute with $A$, so  $$BA=AB,\forall B\in V .$$

Prove that $V$ is a linear space with operations of common matrix add and multiply. And find the basis & dimension of $V$.

> $det(A) \neq 0 $ is clear, and it's easy to prove that $V$ is linear space. But how to find the basis and dimention?

Comment: I would just write down an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrix
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\
b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
Then the equation $AB = BA$ will give you relations among the variable entries of $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $$B=\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ then $$AB=\begin{bmatrix} g & h & i \\ a & b & c \\ 4a-2d+g & 4b-2e+h & 4c-2f+i \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad BA=\begin{bmatrix} b+4c & -2c & a+c \\ e+4f & -2f & d+f \\ h+4i & -2i & g+i \end{bmatrix}.$$

So $B$ is in the space if and only if it simultaneously satisfies all of the equations:
$$\begin{array}{c}
g=b+4c \\
h=-2c \\
i=a+c \\
a=e+4f \\
b=-2f \\
c=d+f \\
4a-2d+g=h+4i \\
4b-2e+h=-2i \\
4c-2f+i=g+i
\end{array}.$$
The solution space is equivalent to the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 
-4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -4 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 
-2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
.$$

This matrix has rank $6$ (found computationally) and consequently has nullity $9-6=3$.  Thus the space in question has dimension $3$.  Trivially,
$$
I=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \quad
2A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 4 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \quad
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & -2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
all commute with $A$.  Further, by inspecting their first rows, we see they are linearly independent.  Thus a basis is $\{I,A,A^{-1}\}$.